# Can i import c++ code from Microsoft visual studio to android studio?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk

Does android studio support android NDK and can I wrap my C++ code from microsoft visual studio using JNI as specified for eclipse? If yes, what are the additional plugins needed if any and the steps required to import my c++ code? 
I'm developing an android app.
I'm using Windows 7 64-bit version and the android studio 1.1.0.

Comment: In this case I suggest using Intellij Idea rather than Android Studio. Is quite similar but is more "general". This IDE is basically for Java so I don't know if you will need additional plugins

Comment: Android Studio still does not officially support the Android NDK.  There are partial solutions posted in various forums on the web, Google to find them.  Official support for the NDK in Android Studio will be happening "soon".